# No mapping have been found

Tags: web8

Hello I have the next problem, when I sent to publish a page, the publication queue keeps empty.

[image]

I saw the next warning in Event Viewer:

[image]

But I have created the Mapping for this publication:

[image]

Could anyone tell me what step I forgot? or what is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try a Get-TtmCdEnvironment?

Comment: Please check that environmental variable on that machine named TRIDION_CM_ENVIRONMENT_ID has the same value as in your CmEnvironment (Tridioncm_local).

Comment: You are rigth Stanislav! now it works fine. If you write this as an answer I will vote you. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please check that environmental variable on that machine named `TRIDION_CM_ENVIRONMENT_ID` has the same value as in your CmEnvironment (Tridioncm_local).